# Input via voice and handwritten works, but not keyboard on app on Galaxy 2

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, text-input

I am working within an app that has text fields for entry.  I can highlight and cut the text if it auto-populates and I can even use the text-to-speech and handwriting input methods.  When I use the keyboard to type, however, it does not populate the text field.  Any thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: galaxy 2? s2 or note 2?

Comment: Model GT-P5113 with Android version 4.1.1

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Comment: Include it in your question.